# Tengo una ip + un puerto y quiero alojar mi app a un dominio

Tags: nodejs, dominio, cloud

Tengo un aplicación web construida en node.js y subida en la cloud, puedo acceder perfectamente a la app con la ip que me suministraron mas el puerto que me arroja el node.js. Pero a la hora de utilizar mi dominio no puedo utilizar la ip y el puerto, se supone que debería utilizar solo la ip, y ¿Cómo se debería gestionar esto?

69.9x.36.7x:4000 <- La ip que está alojada la app y lo que deseo es asociarla con un dominio, y a la hora de asociarlo me pide solo la ip sin puertos, ¿Qué debería hacer?, ¿Algún consejo?

Comment: hola maira, tu pregunta no enriquece los estándares de stackOverflow, te recomiendo que leas [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas redactar una buena pregunta y así poder tener una mejor ayuda, saludos

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, podrías instalarte nginx con el puerto 80 y que nginx redirecciones a tu página.

Otra forma seria cambiando el puerto 4000 por el 80 en tu liveserver o el server que uses. El http por defecto viaja por el puerto 80. Entonces en tu dominio solo pones la ip.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda probaré lo que me recomendaste. :)